# User login in Sqlite?

Tags: android, database

I want to use a log in system in Android with only the username. The code below works only for the first row ( For example my database has names : 1- Joseph 2 - Najib , if i input Joseph it works fine, but if i input Najib or some other value that does not exist in my DB the program apparently keeps looping and does not respond..How can I correct this code to return the message ( either the username being in the DB or an invalid username) accordingly? Do I have an error in the while statement?

```
public void checklogin() {

    DatabaseHelper dbh = new DatabaseHelper(LoginActivity.this);
    DatabaseAdapter dba = new DatabaseAdapter(LoginActivity.this);
    db = dbh.getWritableDatabase();
    TextView usernametry = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.usernametry);
    String usertry = usernametry.getText().toString();

    String[] allColumnsofuserstable = { dba.COLUMN_ID, dba.COLUMN_NAME,
            dba.COLUMN_AGE, dba.COLUMN_GENDER, dba.COLUMN_WEIGHT,
            dba.COLUMN_HEIGHT, dba.COLUMN_CALORIES };

    Log.d("TAG", usertry);

    Cursor mCursor = db.query(dba.TABLE_USERS,
            new String[] { dba.COLUMN_NAME }, null, null, null, null, null,

    mCursor.moveToNext();
    while (!mCursor.isAfterLast()) {
        String k = mCursor.getString(0);
        if (k.equalsIgnoreCase(usertry)) {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,
                    "Logged in as " + mCursor.getString(0).toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            mCursor.moveToNext();
        } else
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "invalid username",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    mCursor.close();
    dbh.close();
    return;
}
```

Comment: Make your question more clearer to the audience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop is broken because you only move the pointer in the cursor (`mCursor.moveToNext();`) in case that the username is found in the database. Cursor can't move after last item and `while (!mCursor.isAfterLast())` never stops.

You need to make sure to always move the cursor. E.g. like so:

```
Cursor mCursor = db.query(dba.TABLE_USERS,
        new String[] { dba.COLUMN_NAME }, null, null, null, null, null,

boolean loggedIn = false;
while (mCursor.moveToNext()) {
    String k = mCursor.getString(0);
    if (k.equalsIgnoreCase(usertry)) {
        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,
                "Logged in as " + mCursor.getString(0).toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        loggedIn = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (!loggedIn)
        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "invalid username",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Or you change your query (see @Waqas) to do the work for you (`LIKE ?` = `equalsIgnoreCase`, `= ?` = `equals`)

```
Cursor mCursor = db.query(dba.TABLE_USERS,
    new String[] { dba.COLUMN_NAME }, dba.COLUMN_NAME + " LIKE ?", new String[]{usertry},
    null, null, null);

if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
    String k = mCursor.getString(0);
    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,
            "Logged in as " + mCursor.getString(0).toString(),
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} else {
        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "invalid username",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: hmm, although i used both codes, it still gives me invalid username for najib, although i can see it in my tAble !

Comment: How do you see it in your table? It's kind of impossible that you can see it but both methods tell you that username does not exist.

Comment: I just refreshed the database and apprently that row "najib" is not there anymore, i guess it is because i manually entered it. 

Is there any way i could get the id of the username returned by the cursor?

Comment: Yes, add it to the projection `new String[] { dba.COLUMN_NAME, dba.COLUMN_ID }`, The can get the id with `long id = mCursor.getLong(1);` then.

Answer (score 1):

The best would be to modify your query to look for string rather than getting all the results and loop through for a lookup.

```
Cursor mCursor = db.query(dba.TABLE_USERS,
new String[] { dba.COLUMN_NAME }, dba.COLUMN_NAME + "=?", new String[]{usertry},
null, null, null);
```

Comment: I have added this code after your statement, and when I enter the 2nd element of my table it gives me invalid although it is valid..


  if(mCursor.moveToFirst()){ Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,
    "Logged in as " + usertry,
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
  
   } else
    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "invalid username",
      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  
  
 
  mCursor.close();
  dbh.close();

Comment: change `mCursor.moveToNext();` to `mCursor.moveToFirst();`

Comment: I do not have any movetonext() in my new code? or are you talking about the first code?